# Synchronize anim time with object rotation C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can I set animation time considering the object rotation. Gameobject have limited rotation on Z axis from 0 to 32,8. And animation have 0,25 sec.

So I have to do something like this: when gameobject is on 0% Z = 0; animation time = 0 too.
When gameobject is on 50% Z = 16,4; animation time = 0,125 so 50% too.

This is what I have, but it does not work:

```
 if(this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z <= 0)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Start");
        animator.speed = 1;
        animator.SetFloat("Time", 0);
    }
    else if(this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z > 0 && this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z <= 8.2f)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Time", 0.0625f);
    }
    else if (this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z > 8.2f && this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z <= 16.4f)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Time", 0.125f);
    }
    else if (this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z > 16.4f && this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z <= 24.6f)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Time", 0.1875f);
    }
    else if (this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z > 24.6f && this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z <= 32.8f)
    {
       animator.SetFloat("Time", 0.25f);
    }
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you would not want to go through `transform.rotation.z`!

`transform.rotation` retuns a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) (also see [Wikipedia Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)) which has not three but **four** components `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` and they all move in ranges `-1` to `1`!

Also using the [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) is not really reliable.

So I would

- Depending on your use case - assuming your object is **only** rotated around Z you could e.g. simply use the angle between `Vector3.up` (world up) and `transform.up` (your objects up) => rotation around Z
- Then instead of using certain steps simply map your angle range `0 to 32,8` to the time range `0 to 0.25`

  See e.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/re-map-a-number-from-one-range-to-another.119437

So it could look like e.g.

```
const float maxAngle = 38.5f;
const float maxTime = 0.25f;

var angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transform.up);
// [optional] make sure angle is valid
angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, 0, maxAngle);

var time = angle / maxAngle * (maxTime);
animator.SetFloat("Time", time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea thanks dude :D I did it like you with small changes and it works:

```
 public Animator anim;
private void Start()
{
    anim.speed = 0;   
}
private void Update()
{
    float angleZ = Mathf.Round(transform.eulerAngles.z * 100)/100;
    float maxAngle = 32.8f;
    float percentage = angleZ / maxAngle;
    anim.Play("Packa1", 0, percentage);
}
```